# Order Pandas dataframe groups by minimum index number, then re-order all other columns within groups based on a 3rd column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

columns=['Order', 'Group_code', 'Grade', 'Contextual_info']

data = np.array([np.arange(6)]*4).T
mydf = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

mydf.Order = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
mydf.Group_code = ['group99','group2','group2','group2','group12','group12']
mydf.Grade = [80,0,60,80,85,70]
mydf.Contextual_info = [5,4,3,2,1,0]

mydf
```

> ```
>    Order Group_code  Grade Contextual_info
> 0      1    group99     80               5
> 1      2     group2      0               4  
> 2      3     group2     60               3          
> 3      4     group2     80               2
> 4      5    group12     85               1
> 5      6    group12     70               0
> ```

Which is ordered by `Order`. I want to preserve the ordering of `Group_code` by `Order`, thus the column values in `Group_code` should not change.

However, *within* each `Group_code` group, I want to order the rows descending by `Grade`. Finally, I will replace `Order` with a new vector of integers 1... n, such that it is still 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 in this example.

Desired result:

> ```
>    Order Group_code  Grade  Contextual_info
>       1    group99     80                 5
>       2     group2     80                 2 
>       3     group2     60                 3
>       4     group2      0                 4
>       5    group12     85                 1
>       6    group12     70                 0
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
In [677]: mydf.Grade = (mydf.groupby('Group_code')['Grade']
                            .transform(pd.Series.sort_values, ascending=False))

In [678]: mydf
Out[678]:
```

> ```
>   Order Group_code  Grade
> 0      1    group99     80
> 1      2     group2     80
> 2      3     group2     60
> 3      4     group2      0
> 4      5    group12     85
> 5      6    group12     70
> ```

Comment: I think simpler one is `mydf.Grade = mydf.groupby('Group_code')['Grade'].transform(sorted,reverse=True)`

Comment: This is great. There's one way I may have oversimplified this. I am trying to sort the *dataframe* not just one column. This was probably unclear because the example was so minimal. In the real world there are dozens of other columns that should also get sorted. Is it easy to tweak this for that? I just tweaked the example to make this more clear.